# Default route is not working in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular5

I have setup lazy routing like below,

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
{ path : '' , redirectTo : '/posts' , pathMatch:'full' },    
{ path : 'posts',  component:PostsComponent ,  children: [
    {path : 'contact' , component : ContactComponent },
    {path : ':slugurl' , component : SinglepostComponent }, 
    {path : 'category/:category' , component : PostfeedComponent },   
    {path : '' , component : PostfeedComponent },             
]},
{ path : 'about', loadChildren : './aboutme/aboutme.module#AboutmeModule' },    
{ path : 'admin',  loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' , canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] },  
{ path : 'login', loadChildren : './login/login.module#LoginModule' },]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

But its always redirect to about path, As you can see I have given the default route to post though. Please let me know where I should make the correction to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
export const appRoutes : Routes = [
    { path : '' , redirectTo : '/posts' , pathMatch:'full' },    
    { path : 'posts',  component:PostsComponent ,  children: [
        {path : 'contact' , component : ContactComponent },
        {path : ':slugurl' , component : SinglepostComponent }, 
        {path : 'category/:category' , component : PostfeedComponent },   
        {path : '' , component : PostfeedComponent },             
    ]},
    { path : 'about', loadChildren : './aboutme/aboutme.module#AboutmeModule' },    
    { path : 'admin',  loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' , canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] },  
    { path : 'login', loadChildren : './login/login.module#LoginModule' },]

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
   ],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then import AppRoutingModule in app.module.ts.

Each Lazy Loaded module will need their own routes.ts file.

Comment: Thanks for solution, will give it a shot today and will let you know :)

Comment: Sounds good. I can go into more detail about lazy loading if you need more help.

Comment: Hi, It worked. But I didn't understand why previous one is not working ? Would you like to explain it please

Comment: Yes, so all you have to do is export your appRoutes object and then use it inside of NgModule imports array as RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes).It seemed like what you originally were doing was too much, or you weren't importing it.

Comment: No, That's the thing, I was even importing it in my imports array. But it worked fine till Angular 4, recently I upgraded to v5, so it broke. :)

Comment: Strange, either way, the example I gave you is what I have been using from Angular 2-5.

Comment: I am using angular 7 and it's working . you save my day :)